# Which approach to prefer to dynamically manage database requests in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

In case of dynamically creating connections to the database I've come up with following two approaches after searching the internet.

1. Managing different database connections using LRU Queuing Algorithm at the backend. (connection pooling)
2. Using a single connection, and using the mongoose's `useDB` functionality to switch among databases.
   Assumptions are, there can be 100 databases at the same time.

This thing is ticking off my mind for a while, and I need supportive pros and cos for the two approaches.

My intuition is to use the `useDB` method, but cannot support it with valid reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the driver you are using permits switching databases, you should definitely do that. I am unfamiliar with Mongoose but in Ruby it is massively more efficient to use a single client instance and configure it for the different databases.

Comment: That was helpful. How many databases have you tried to connect to? Have you faced any throttling issues?

Comment: In Ruby it doesn't matter how many different databases are used, they use the same underlying client and operations are limited by the connection pool size and Ruby concurrency which isn't great. There is no throttling done by drivers.